# Can you set requestTimeout to below 1 minute in IIS asp net core?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Can you set `requestTimeout` to below 1 minute in IIS asp net core?

The following screenshot shows that the granularity is `00:01:00` which is 1 minute.

Does that mean that you cannot set seconds? So cannot set 90 seconds, for example?

I want to be able to set the timeout to be a few seconds, say 10 seconds.

[image: requestTimeout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:01:00" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Foo.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Why? Would you want to do that?

Comment: It's a requirement for my api. Also, why have the format hh:mm:ss if the seconds cannot be set? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I agree that format is strange (it's a timespan), but setting a time second request timeout for your entire site seems aggressive? Why not write the code to account for that instead of relying on timeouts? 

BTW this timeout just aborts the connection, the back end is still running.